# GraphQL - Nullable is not a repeatable annotation type

Tags: amazon-web-services, android-studio, graphql, code-generation, aws-amplify

I use AWS in the project:

```
implementation('com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-appsync:3.0.1')
implementation('org.eclipse.paho:org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3:1.2.0')
implementation('org.eclipse.paho:org.eclipse.paho.android.service:1.1.1')
implementation("com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-s3:2.16.11")
implementation('com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-mobile-client:2.16.3@aar') {
    transitive = true
}
implementation('com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-auth-userpools:2.16.3@aar') {
    transitive = true
}
```

And faced the issue that not able to build application because of issues in generated code:

```
package com.amazonaws.amplify.generated.graphql;
import javax.annotation.Nonnull;
import javax.annotation.Nullable;
....

public static class ListUsers {
final @Nullable @Nullable List<Item> items;

public ListUsers(@Nonnull String __typename, @Nullable @Nullable List<Item> items,
    @Nullable String nextToken) {
  this.__typename = Utils.checkNotNull(__typename, "__typename == null");
  this.items = items;
  this.nextToken = nextToken;
}

public @Nonnull String __typename() {
  return this.__typename;
}

public @Nullable @Nullable List<Item> items() {
  return this.items;
}
```

and build fails because of `error: Nullable is not a repeatable annotation type`

what can be the reason? Is it possible to make some workaround to fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I run in exactly the same problem yesterday. The AWS Android team moved my issue request to the AppSync team.

You can track progress here: https://github.com/awslabs/aws-mobile-appsync-sdk-android/issues/273#

Comment: Hi @micstepper, what is your `androidx.navigation` version? found for me it fails with `2.3.0-alpha05` but works fine with `2.3.0-alpha04'`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and my project didn't use the navigation library, the workaround was to revert Hilt to version 2.35.1 and Gradle to version 4.2.2

```
dependencies {
    ...
    classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.2"
    classpath "com.google.dagger:hilt-android-gradle-plugin:2.35.1"
}

dependencies {
    // Hilt
    implementation "com.google.dagger:hilt-android:2.35.1"
    kapt "com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:2.35.1"
}
```